# Формирование массива данных из csv файла

Tags: php

Есть небольшой файл в формате `csv`, каждый столбец которого я чоху записать в массив. Для этого я пишу следующий код:

```
$handle = fopen("new_price.csv", "r");

$id          = [];
$price       = [];

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $length=count($data);      
    for( $i=0; $i < $length; $i++ ){ 
        if( $i == 1 ) array_push($id, iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251", $data[$i]));
        if( $i == 3 ) array_push($price_from, iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $data[$i]));
    }    
}

array_shift($id);
array_shift($price_from);

foreach($price as $key => $v){
    echo $key." ".$v."<br>";
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если в столбце есть хотя бы несколько русских букв, то строка в столбце получается пустой, подскажите как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

применил `mb_convert_encoding` и заработало

```
mb_convert_encoding($data[$i], 'utf-8', "windows-1251");
```